# Store data between Program Runs Java

Tags: java

Short Version: I need to store some data between runs of a java program.The data will be of the form of a table.Is there anything that can let do something like a sql query in java??THE SOLUTION MUST BE ABLE TO RUN ON AN OFFLINE COMPUTER.

Long Version: The user will be entering some data daily and i want something like a sql table in java. The program will run on a computer that is NOT CONNECTED TO THE INTERNET and so i need a truly local way to store data(Lots of it).Also preferably the data should be stored in such a way that it is not easily accessible to the end user(as in ,he should not be able to double click the file and simply read its contents)

Major Constraint: On searching online i found many people were using localhost to solve similar problems but that facility is not available to me as i CANNOT INSTALL ANYTHING on the target computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Store it in an xml-file
2. Store it in an local installed database

You can install a database like mysql or use a in memory database like sqlite or hbase or apache derby, which is included in java 6

Comment: HBase is not in-memory. I think you meant HSQLDB.

Answer (score 4):

If a simple data file is not good enough, how about using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) with a [JDBC backend](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC)? It will allow you to have an SQL database stored in a regular file with no dependency on any kind of server. Alternatively, there are many other embedded DB engines that you could use, depending on your needs.

EDIT:

By the way, most (if not all) DB engines that I know of do not obfuscate the data before storing them in the filesystem. The data will be fragmented, but parts of it will be visible if you force an editor to open the file (e.g. using "Open with..." in Windows).

There is also nothing to stop your user from accessing the data using the command line utility of the selected DB engine. If you want to obfuscate the data you have to do it in your code. Keep in mind that this will *not* stop a determined person - if your application can read it offline, so can everyone else.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to encrypt all files before closing and decrypting them before starting up ?

Comment: @DarkKnight: Depending on the amount of data, your application may have to descrypt a _lot_ of data just to start-up. This is not a good idea IMHO, especially if you do not implement some kind of progress indicator for your users. There are also issues with what happens if you application dies before it finishes the en/decryption process (temporary files etc). You would also need more disk space for temporary storage.

Comment: @DarkKnight: Since the key would be stored in your application anyway, this is just a form of obfuscation. IMHO it would be best to just obfuscate any data as you insert it in the DB, unless you mind someone knowing how many rows and columns there are in the tables. A simple XOR  encryption, perhaps with a checksum, would stop any casual user from reading or tampering with the data - anything more is probably overkill. Anyone willing to defeat _that_ would most probably be able to recover the key of any encryption scheme that you use anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use an embedded database (like Apache Derby, HSQLDB, H2) so that you don't have to run a database server on the machine. The data will be stored locally on the target machine and it won't be human readable.

Comment: +1 for an embedded database (especially because of the "lots of data")